# Can one force both rotate a body around an axis and also cause translation?

Tags: kinematics, torque, free-body-diagram, rotational-kinematics, rotation

If a solid cylinder is rolling without slipping down an incline, and the force of friction is applied tangentially to the edge of the cylinder in the opposite direction as torque.

However, I do not understand why in the $\sum F =ma$ equation, the frictional torque is still included as an X component. To me this seems very strange, as I thought torque does not affect the motion of center of mass.

My question is: Why is the Force of friction included in both the Sum of Forces and Sum of Torques equations. Since the friction is applied tangentially, why does that affect the force on the center of mass?

Comment: In the first line you say that force of gravity is applied at center of mass then it is applied tangentially... make up your mind

Comment: I corrected it, only the force of friction is applied tangentially.

Comment: what do u mean by the sum of forces = ma is not included as x component? I stopped understanding after that part

Comment: Your point of reference is?

Comment: I essentially mean that when solving for translational acceleration, the equation is mgsin(θ)-FrictionalForce=ma, but I am confused as to why it wouldn't be just mgsin(θ)=ma since the torque is applied perfectly tangentially.

Comment: First of all solving the force parallel to surface does not give you the torque. The torque is a completely different quantity.



To talk about torque you need to first define an axis of rotation for the object to rotate around. Next you need to find the vector from that axis to the point where you applied force. Cross product this vector and force vector to get torque.



Torque measures amount of rotation. And is indepdent of translation.

Comment: As per right now I think you may be misunderstanding a lot of things. Might want to hit the books of where you learned torque again. Then, maybe if you still have the same query (or around these lines) edit this question.

Comment: To clarify my question: the axis of rotation is the center of the cylinder, also the center of mass. I understand why the force of friction is included in the torque equation for the cylinder, as it is applied perpendicularly at the cylinder's radius. However, I do not understand why this same force is included in the sum of forces equation when solving for the translational acceleration of the cylinder's center of mass.

Comment: See, imagine the cylinder was a point particle. Then if you keep the same axis and all you would still see that it is moving by your force equation.

Now, the ramp and all then keep the cylinder along an axis and on the edge you give the push equivalent to how much the frictional force does on it in the incline case, then you can make it go round and round wheeeee

Comment: Did that answer your question or do you have more? I am happy to help ;D

Answer (score 0):

The torque of the gravitational field is counted with respect to the touchpoint of the cylinder to an incline. Friction force keeps/guarantees the touchpoint to be "stationary"(without slipping). The friction force creates torque wrt to the cylinder center, which is moving down(not stationary). The friction force-torque vector does not intersect the gravitation torque in the opposite direction to compensate for it.

Answer (score 0):

Force may contribute to angular or rotational motion.  As such, we say that they can contribute a torque.  But that doesn't mean that it's not still a force.  So a given force may be simultaneously responsible for linear momentum changes and rotational momentum changes.

> ...the frictional torque is still included as an X component. To me this seems very strange, as I thought torque does not affect the motion of center of mass.

It is true that pure torque would not affect the motion of the center of mass.  But friction in this case is not a pure torque.  It is a force with a defined direction and does modify the center of mass.

This is actually quite easy to show.  Take a cylinder and drop it down a rough ramp (where it rolls) and a slick ramp (where it slides).  Gravity and the normal forces are identical, but the cylinder on the rough surface falls more slowly.  This is because the force from friction retards the acceleration of the object.

All forces on an object contribute to the sum of forces for determination of linear momentum change.  Just because it can be considered tangential doesn't matter here.  It does mean that force will also create a torque, but that doesn't matter for the motion of the center of mass.

Comment: If a "pure torque" is applied to one end of a rod floating in space, does that mean the center of mass of the rod wouldn't move? Because I have gotten a conflicting answer on whether a force applied perfectly perpendicularly to one end of a rod floating in space with no air resistance will contribute to motion of the center of mass. Could you give an example of a "pure torque"?

Comment: You can't apply a pure torque with a single force.  You can mathematically describe it, but to realize it, you'd need a force couple.  The two together can supply a torque, but cancel out each other's contribution to linear changes.  A single force applied *anywhere* will always change the velocity of the center of mass.